# Ifelse in R and trying to create new data frame with this statement

Tags: r

I have a data frame as "tab1" having name and salary ,now i am trying to create a new table as "tab2" with bonus based on their salary in tab1,i am getting error as " object 'tab2' not found ".  below is my code

```
tab2$bonus <- ifelse(tab1$salary < 1000, 0.5, tab1$salary)
```

How to resolve it ,thanks in advance

Comment: Because you don't have a `tab2` object.  Try `tab1$bonus` or create a `tab2` object i.e. `tab2 <- data.frame(bonus = rep(NA, nrow(tab1))`

Comment: thanks akrun , i am getting that one what u mention , but i need to create a new data frame / table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a `tab2` object before doing `tab2$bonus`.  Assuming that the OP wanted 'tab2' as a data.frame,

```
tab2 <- data.frame(bonus = ifelse(tab1$salary< 1000 , 
                                        0.5 ,tab1$salary))
```